Darlington Pair Amplifer

I am attempting to drive a 8 ohm 2watt speaker using a Darlington pair amplifier circuit
however this turns out to be the current flowing through my load
I feel like i have connect my load incorrectly however i am not sure
the current flowing through R2 seems to amplified quite a bit however it includes the D.C bias
How can i modify my configuration to act correctly as an amplifier to drive my speaker with my amplified input signal
Here are my calculations for the component values in the circuit
(you can ignore the comments they are just for me to verbalize why i am doing things so i can recall why i made certain choices)





It looks like C3 is shorted out. What type of amplifier are you going for here? As drawn, this will only act to amplify current, while maintaining (close to) the same voltage.

from what i understand a Darlington pair as an amplifier would only amplify the current yes, but couldn't that current drive a speaker aslong as it dissipated enough power across its load ? also i dont see a C3 in the circuit what are you refering to ?

I meant C2, sorry. There are ways to amplify voltage as well; I just wanted to be sure that this was what you wanted, as I frequently see circuits like yours mistakenly used when voltage amplification is desired. You probably do need to modify the biasing somewhat though; voltage divider bias tends to work better.

@Hearth i dont see how changing the bias would help, my calculations seem to suggest it is correct, i am probably missing something but i just dont know what. I have added my hand analysis in to the post, why would using a voltage divider biasing be more effective ?

Was this built on a solderless breadboard? A custom designed PCB?

@MathKeepsMeBusy i have yet to build this, currently in the simulation phase

@OfficialPyramid You only have one active drive quadrant, in concept. And I'm almost sure you have C2 bypassed with a wire that runs right through it. So the schematic may be badly composed. Get the netlist for it and post it up, please.

You should add a R across B-E of Q2 which will ensure that Q1 is biased up and maintains consistent performance (vs. VOUT). Something like 100 Ω would be reasonable

Try running the simulation for about 2 seconds.

Bipolar drivers are needed to handle each polarity of the signal, carefully biased with about 1% of the amount of maximum DC current to reduce crossover distortion.  These can be push-pull NPN Darlingtons or complementary PNP/NPN  emitter followers and many other variations intended to make the output impedance always about 1% or so of the load. Higher power demands even lower damping impedance to create this damping factor with negative feedback to reduce distortion.  Take a look at what Carvin did over 40 years ago.  https://carvinaudio.com/pages/power-amplifier-schematic after your 2 s.

An understanding of, or simulation of a darlington pair emitter follower would have revealed its output voltage constraints:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

You clearly can't get more than 7V out, or less than zero, so a sinusoidal output will have maximum amplitude 3.5V (peak), corresponding to \$\frac{3.5}{\sqrt 2} = 2.5V_{RMS}\$. Even if everything else worked fine, maximum sinusoidal power into 8Ω would be only:
$$ P_{RMS} = \frac{V^2}{R} = \frac{2.5^2}{8} = 0.78W_{RMS} $$
You would want to centre your output at about +3.5V. Given the 1.4V DC difference from base to emitter, add 1.4V to that, for a quiescent base potential of +4.9V. That requires a resistor potential divider (consisting of R1 and R2) at the input:
$$
\begin{aligned}
8 \times \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} &= 4.9 \\ \\
\frac{R_1}{R_2} &= \frac{3.1}{4.9}
\end{aligned}
$$
To use an AC input centered at 0V will require AC coupling to the junction of this divider, with a capacitor:

simulate this circuit
This is very different from your own implementation, which I don't understand at all. My design here produces this:

As it stands, the output is offset by +3.5V, causing quiescent current in the load of \$\frac{3.5V}{8\Omega} = 0.44A\$. This is obviously undesirable in a speaker, since it introduces a permanent deflection of the diaphragm, and so you want to also AC couple the speaker. This is where it gets difficult.
The emitter follower can source current, but cannot sink any, meaning that the transistors can raise output potential, but cannot bring it down. The only element causing emitter potential to fall is the load itself.
If you put a capacitor between OUT and the load, the transistors can charge it, but not discharge. This mandates a DC load at all times, which can no longer be the speaker, since that will be isolated by the capacitor. The algebra to calculate an appropriate value for the DC load is not trivial, but we can use the principle that output impedance should be small compared to load (speaker) impedance, to minimise attenuation. I'll use 4Ω:

simulate this circuit

There is a lot of distortion, as you can see. At best the distortion is minor asymmetry caused by the different current sourcing and sinking abilities of the amplifier, at worst it is outright clipping, as shown. That clipping means that you must further constrain input/output amplitude, if you want the signal to be reproduced "reasonably faithfully", and your maximum output power will suffer too, as a consequence. At a guess, I'd say an input/output constrained to ±2.5V is the best you can expect.
Worse than that, you now have quiescent current in R3:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{R3} &= \frac{V_{R3}}{R_3} \\ \\
&= \frac{3.5V}{4\Omega} \\ \\
&= 0.88A \\ \\
P_{R3} &= \frac{{V_{R3}}^2}{R_3} \\ \\
&= \frac{{3.5V}^2}{4\Omega} \\ \\
&= 3W
\end{aligned}
$$
This is why nobody uses this design in applications requiring fidelity or efficiency. The solution is a push-pull pair, replacing R3 with another emitter follower to sink current, matching the one sourcing it here.
One more thing; a BC337 can't deal with the current or power that you are asking of it. Check out the maximum current \$I_C\$ that it is specified to handle in the BC337 datasheet. It will dissipate power similar to R3, about 3W (or more), and its soul will leave its tiny little TO-92 body quicker than you can turn off the power. That is why, in my implementations here I have employed a beefy TIP41 to deal with that current and the consequent power dissipation. It will still require heat-sinking to dispense with those 3W of heating.

What you show is basically correct. The Darlington pair acts as an emitter-follower, and because it's single-ended it will have a DC bias. (Your output cap does seem to be shorted out though.)
I messed with this a bit to modify the bias and add a collector load. Performance is a bit better (simulate it here):

While this works, it doesn't put out much power, and it has a voltage gain of less than 1.
This Sziklai circuit works a bit better (simulate it here):

The resistor on the NPN emitter sets gain.
If you’re interested in more audio amp approaches, have a look here: https://www.sound-au.com/articles/cmpd-vs-darl.htm
For a speaker drive I would recommend considering a Class AB circuit. This will get you closer to full power with much greater efficiency.

(I don't know "Sziklai circuit". I don't see Sziklai pair.)
